# Counting number of cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let $G = \big(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, that is the multiplicative group modulo $n$. For some $d$ coprime to $n$, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ generated by $d$. As $G$ is abelian, $H$ is normal in $G$, hence the set of left cosets $G/H$ forms a group. What is the order of $G/H$ in terms of $n$ and $d$?

Comment: What do _you_ think? Take a wild guess. Try it out with a few examples (like $n = 5$ and $d = 2$ or $d = 4$) to see what might happen. Make a better guess. Try to prove it.

Comment: I have been trying to get a closed form expression for the order of $G/H$ for weeks, and have not been successful. That is why I have put this question up here.

Answer (score 1):

$H=\{d^j: 1\leq j\leq $ ord$(d)\}$  $\pmod n $ where  ord$(d)$ is the least $m\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $d^m\equiv 1 \pmod n . $ And $|G/H|=|G|/|H|=\phi (n)/$ ord$(d).$......($\phi$ is the totient.)

Comment: Of course, but is there a closed form expression for it in terms of $n$ and $d$? I couldn't find one for ord($d$).

Comment: @AalokThakkar That's more or less as good as it gets. If you don't like using $\operatorname{ord}_n(d)$, are you sure you're OK with using $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @Arthur. I often type the wrong symbol for the totient. So I always name it .